# How to set collection of *ngFor from protractor in Angular 4.0?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e, angular-e2e

app.component.html

```
<div class="student-list" *ngFor="let student of students">
    <p>{{student.name}}</p>
</div>
```

I want to test whether all students have name. But `students` is a list which is getting set in app.component.ts.

Now how should I set the `students` from protractor?

I have done following

```
element(by.binding('students')).sendKeys(['abc', 'xyz']);
```

But this is not working, it throws `Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined`. 
What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

angular selectors such as **`by.model`** and **`by.binding`** are not supported **`Angular2`** and above versions.

As per the **[docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.1.2#compatibility)**

> Protractor works with AngularJS versions greater than 1.0.6/1.1.4, and
>   is compatible with Angular applications. Note that for Angular apps,
>   the by.binding() and by.model() locators are not supported. We
>   recommend using by.css().

you can see the examples here

https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#e2e-tests

**EDIT**

To solve your issue you can use Id

**HTML**

```
<div  *ngFor="let student of students" id="students">
    <p  class="student-list"> {{student.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**test**

```
var students = element.all(by.id('students')).all(by.css('student-list'));
var firstOrg = organizations.get(0);
it('should have an org with specific name', function() {
    expect(firstOrg.getText()).toEqual('Name you expect');
});
```

Comment: okay. But if I use by.css like element(by.css('.student-list')).sendKeys(['abc', 'xyz']); This also fails saying No element found using locator: By(css selector, .student-list)

Comment: it should be without .

Comment: tried without .  like element(by.css('student-list')).sendKeys(['abc', 'xyz']); still no element found

Comment: you can use element by class, i added an example above

Comment: You are right about accessing the students collection. But before accessing students collection, it to be set with some value SendKeys(['xyz', 'abc']). Can you share some ideas how to set collection?

Comment: you should do some research on that, even i have not much idea on that. mark if the answer helped

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable inputs !!

Comment: i think you should do like  students.get(0).sendKeys('abc');
   students.get(1).sendKeys('xyz');

Comment: initialiiy students is empty or has 0 elements. So students.get(0) or students.get(anything) will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="student-list" *ngFor="let student of students">
    <p *ngIf="student.name">{{student.name}}</p>
</div>
```

This is one of the way using which you can display only those users who has name.